# Add significance bars to proportions plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot of proportions and I would like to add significance bars showing the statistical differences between groups. I would like to use the [`ggsignif`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html) package to create a similar like this:

[image]

I have tried using the `ggsignif` package and `ggplot2`, but the results do not appear to work for tests of proportions (e.g. chi.square)

My data look like this:

```
Input =("
        Group  Yes  No
        1       10       90
        2       30       70
        3       20       80
        ")

test_table = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(Input),
                              header=TRUE))
```

And my initial plot looks like this:

```
ggplot(test_table, 
       aes(x=Group, y=Yes)) 
    + geom_col()
```

Comment: Well you're showing (what looks like) raw counts, so how do you expect to show "significance bars" for proportions? What proportions are you calculating and what null hypothesis are you testing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The proportions I am testing are the 'yes' vs. 'no' columns in the test_table. The null hypothesis is that the two categorical variables are independent in some population.

Comment: *"The proportions I am testing are the 'yes' vs. 'no' columns in the test_table"* I'm confused. That sounds like you're after a binomial test to me.  *"The null hypothesis is that the two categorical variables are independent in some population"* Which two categorical variables? I struggle to understand how a chi-square test comes into play here. A chi-square test of independence tests whether there is an association of values for multiple categories. Provided I understood you correctly you seem to want to test whether the ratios of Yes/No for different groups are the same.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, I want to test whether the ratios of Yes/No for different groups are the same and then to plot those differences using significance bars on a barplot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a possibility.

We first calculate pairwise comparisons between pairs of proportions (correcting for multiple hypothesis testing) using base R's `pairwise.prop.test` (see `?pairwise.prop.test` and `?prop.test` for details):

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
res <- pairwise.prop.test(as.matrix(test_table[, -1])) %>%
    tidy() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(contains("group")), ~factor(.x, test_table$Group))
res
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  group1 group2 p.value
#  <fct>  <fct>    <dbl>
#1 2      1      0.00235
#2 3      1      0.149
#3 3      2      0.149
```

I use `broom::tidy` to tidy the output of `pairwise.prop.test`; this is not a critical dependence but saves us some time.

Then we can plot the `Yes/(Yes + No)` proportions and overlay p-values from the pairwise tests proportion tests

```
library(ggsignif)
df <- test_table %>%
    mutate(Prop = Yes / (Yes + No))

ggplot(df, aes(Group, Prop, group = Group)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_signif(
        xmin = as.integer(res$group1),
        xmax = as.integer(res$group2),
        y_position = 0.3 + df$Prop,
        annotation = format(res$p.value, digits = 3),
        tip_length = 0.1)
```

[image]